# Using Mock() in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Can you give some clear examples of uses of the Mock() in Django unittests?
I want to understand it more clearly.

**Update:** I've figured out some things, so I share it below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Part 1: Basics

```
from mock import Mock
```

Mock object is an object that is a kind of a `Dummy` for the code that
we want not to be executed, but for which we want to know some information (number of calls, call arguments). Also we might want to specify a return value for that code.

Let us define simple function:

```
def foo(value):
    return value + value
```

Now we're ready to create a Mock object for it:

```
mock_foo = Mock(foo, return_value='mock return value')
```

Now we can check it:

```
>>> foo(1)
2
>>> mock_foo(1)
'mock return value'
```

And get some information on calls:

```
>>> mock_foo.called
True
>>> mock_foo.call_count
1
>>> mock_foo.call_args
((1,), {})
```

Available attributes of Mock() instance are:

```
call_args       func_code       func_name
call_args_list  func_defaults   method_calls
call_count      func_dict       side_effect
called          func_doc        
func_closure    func_globals
```

They're quite self-explanatory.

### Part 2: `@patch` decorator

The `@patch` decorator allows us to easily create mock objects for imported objects (classes or methods). It is very useful while writing unit-tests.

Let us assume that we have following module `foo.py`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def foo(value):
        return value + value
```

Let us write a test for @patch decorator.
We are going to patch method `foo` in class `Foo` from module `foo`. Do not forget imports.

```
from mock import patch
import foo

@patch('foo.Foo.foo')
def test(mock_foo):
    # We assign return value to the mock object
    mock_foo.return_value = 'mock return value'
    f = foo.Foo()
    return f.foo(1)
```

Now run it:

```
>>> test()
'mock return value'
```

Voila! Our method successfully overridden.

Comment: Ah, finally an explanation on mock's and patch's that I can understand!!

Answer (score 1):

[The Mock site](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) has some really nice API documentation that cover all of this.  Note that patch replaces all instances of `foo.Foo.foo` where ever they are called.  It is not the preferred way to mock something but can be the only way -- see open().